# Spring boot webapp deployement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment

I had created a portfolio website by using spring boot, as we all know that heruku is now paid and railway.app is also paid now from previous few weeks.There is one website know as RENDER is available for deploaying the websites that are made by using spring boot, but its servise is very slow, the websites doesn't even runs on the browser after a day of deployement.
In my portfolio website, i had only used emailApi from java and nothing else like database, so it should be easy to deploy.

I want recommendation of a website to deploy my  Spring bott web application which should be free because I am just a student and I don't have money to spend. The deployment should be smooth and easy also the speed of website should be well enough.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking for recommendations is off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. If you're a student, maybe ask if your university can host. Or put the code on github. As a hiring manager I'll rather look at your code than how your app looks in the browser anyway.